# CSV reading with Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, file-handling

I have about 20 rows of data with 4 columns each. 
How do I print only a certain row. Like for instance print only Row 15, Row 16 and Row 17.
When I try row[0] it only prints out the first **column** but not the entire row. I am confused here.

Right now I can read out each of the rows by doing:

for lines in reader:
    print(lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have relatively small dataset you can read the entire thing and select the rows you want

```
reader = csv.reader(open("somefile.csv"))
table = list(reader) # reads entire file
for row in table[15:18]:
    print(row)
```

You could also save a bit of time by only reading as much as you need

```
with open("somefile.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for _ in range(14):
        next(reader)  # dicarc
    for _ in range(3):
        print(next(reader))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try iloc method

```
import pandas as pd
## suppose you want 15 row only
data=pd.read_csv("data.csv").iloc[14,:]
```